# Где хранится значение value

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть вот такое поле ввода:

```
<div class="finam-ui-controls-textbox-inner">
<input id="user-dialog-auth-username" type="text" name="login" maxlength="50" value="">
</div>
```

Когда я кликаю по нему и ввожу текст, он соответственно вводится, но "user-dialog-auth-username" - не изменяется, значение value="" - не меняется.

При этом я искал значение во всем документе:

```
{
   
if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("Hello") == -1)
{
console.log("not equal");  
}
else
{
    console.log("equal");  
}
    
}
```

В документе его тоже - нет.

Хотя когда я вызываю:

```
 let elem = document.getElementById("user-dialog-auth-username");
 console.log(elem.value);
```

Значение выводится именно то, которое я ввел.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138234/discussion-on-question-by-staxcelrom----value).

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте на элемент event и забирайте value из input

```
const elem = document.getElementById("user-dialog-auth-username");

let valueInputUser = '';

elem.addEventListener('change', e => {
  valueInputUser = e.target.value;
});
```

Comment: Я так и сделал, но мне просто интересно, в какой элемент DOM - помещается значение, которое я ввожу в поле input.