# Найти значение value через metationObserver

Tags: javascript

Прошу пожалуйста позволить продолжит тему: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435582/Где-хранится-значение-value?noredirect=1#comment2560880_1435582](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1435582/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-value?noredirect=1#comment2560880_1435582)

На сайте есть вот такое поле ввода:

```
<div class="finam-ui-controls-textbox-inner">
<input id="user-dialog-auth-username" type="text" name="login" maxlength="50" value="">
</div>
```

Я запускаю следующий код:

```
{
   
function my_func_observer(event, observer_)
{

      for(let i=0; i<event.length;i++)
   {

       console.log(event[i].target.className);


      if(event[i].target.className == "finam-ui-controls-textbox-inner")
      {

       console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
       setTimeout(() => {  console.log("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"); }, 200000);
    
      }
   }

         
}



  

const my_mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(my_func_observer);

let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("finam-ui-controls-textbox-inner")[0];
    
my_mutationObserver.observe(elem , { childList:true, attributes:true, characterData: true, subtree:true });

}
```

То есть на любое изменение в поле ввода (в объекте DOM - поле ввода) должен вызваться колбек. Но не вызывается.

А я ожидаю увидеть вызов функции, так как в прошлой теме подсказали вот такое:

> Клик и ввод текста - это событие. Событие навешивается при помощи
> addEventListener на объект DOM (такие как Element, Document, Window -
> они есть в списке тут:
> developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)‌​. Т.е.
> работа происходит в это время с DOM...... а при изменении чего-то в
> DOM не означает сиюминутное изменение в HTML

То есть я делаю вывод, что ввод текста - должен менять объект дом связанный сполем ввода, а значит mutationObserver - должен перехватить это изменение. Но не перехватывает получается.

Почему так ?

Comment: как из _ввод текста - должен менять объект дом связанный сполем ввода_ следует, что _mutationObserver - должен перехватить это изменение_???

Comment: @Grundy, ну mutationObserver - перехватывает же изменения ?

Comment: **Какие конкретно изменения** он перехватывает?

Comment: @Grundy, добавление или удаление дочерних элементов, изменение атрибутов, изменение значения текстового содержимого, потомков целевого элемента.

Comment: и тут нет ничего про свойство `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#parameters) не смотрит на изменения свойств. Вот если вы будете менять аттрибуты (например тот же `value`), тогда будет ловить:

```js
const elementToObserve = document.querySelector('div');

let count = 0;

const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('callback that runs when observer is triggered', ++count);
});

observer.observe(elementToObserve, {
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true,
  childList: true
});

elementToObserve.addEventListener('input', (e) => elementToObserve.setAttribute('value', e.target.value))
```

```html
<div>
  <input value="Change me">
  <input value="Change me">
  <input value="Change me">
  <input value="Change me">
  <input value="Change me">
  <input value="Change me">
  <input value="Change me">
</div>
```

Comment: Так я меняю value же ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom `value` как аттрибут и `value` как свойство - это разные вещи

Comment: а, как в данном случае отличить value, как свойство и value, как значение ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom Отличить кому? Если `MutationObserver`, то никак, если вам надо отличать, то как минимум в разметке вы должны видеть аттрибуты, а не свойства